# .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter não está passando o segundo parâmetro

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp

Tenho um sistema em ASP Classico, e estou tentando executar uma procedure SQL Server passando dois parâmetros.

Originalmente passava apenas uma data selecionada em um datepicker e funcionava, agora quero passar um valor int obtido em um combo (contendo os valores 1, 2 e 3).

Os valores estão sendo enviados por meio da função quando clico no botão:

```
var data = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
var homolog = document.getElementById("homolog").value;

Outros comandos...

xmlreq.open("GET", "carregahorarios.asp?data="+data + "&homolog=" + homolog, true);
```

A página carregahorarios.asp recebe esses valores:

```
data = request.QueryString("data")
homolog = request.QueryString("homolog")
```

E a criação da chamada para a procedure:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
With cmd
   ' Set up DB connection to use, set the type of SQL command
   .ActiveConnection = conexao
   .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   .CommandText = "HorarioDisponivelHomolog"

   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@dataselec", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, datanew&" 00:00:00")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@homolog", adInteger, adParamInput)

   set rs = .Execute
End With
```

O parâmetro que está dando problema é esse @homolog.

Quando clico no botão que chama a procedure dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
O procedimento ou a função 'HorarioDisponivelHomolog' espera o parâmetro '@homolog' que não foi fornecido.
```

Answer (score 0):

Inclui o campo homolog como valor no final da linha, junto com o tamanho

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@homolog", adInteger, adParamInput, 1 homolog)
```